# How to deal with error message - Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] - using pycharm and anacoda

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, anaconda

I'm learning python and want this code to work.

```
import pandas

df =pandas.DataFrame([[2,4,6],[10,20,30]])
print(df)
```

This is what I get:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I'm using pycharm with anaconda environment. Hopefully I've set the environment and interpreter up right. It says I have numpy version 1.16.2 installed, however it won't let me upgrade to version 1.17.0

Tried installing, uninstalling and upgrading through packages and terminal and upgraded pip. This is what I get:

```
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.16.4
    Uninstalling numpy-1.16.4:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.16.4
Successfully installed numpy-1.17.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 19.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Python>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/ca/94d32a6516ed197a491d17d46595ce58a83cbb2fca280414e57cd86b84dc/pip-19.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 114kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.1.1
Successfully installed pip-19.2.1
```

I'm very new to all this and probably doing something wrong, someone please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3cx3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try and use the Anaconda GUI Navigator, available through the standard download of Anaconda Software Bundle.

You can easily manipulate virtual environments and install/uninstall different packages, using the self-explanatory GUI. I found it very simple and a good way to start using Anaconda and Python:

[image]